# Possible to run multiple independent video feeds from a single PC/Max/Linux?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dashboard

We'd like to set up a monitor in each of our employee's offices that has their personal "dashboard" displayed (just a web browser showing a special URL for their stuff), for 8 employees.

Is it possible to do this by having a single machine in a server closet somewhere that is sending out 8 independent video feeds (VGA, DVI, or HDMI) ?

I was thinking of something like OSX or Linux workspaces, where we could just have Firefox open in each workspace, and each workspace/firefox would show the dashboard web page for that employee video feed.  Then each workspace would be sent out via a different video output cable?

Anyone ever tried something like this?  I was hoping something could be cobbled together with off-the-shelf hardware and software, rather than purchasing some expensive custom video distribution system.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at this a while ago an for my company when I was doing a digital signage project, it did not turn out economical due to the costs involved for cabling and the graphics cards.

In the end, we got very small embedded VESA mount machines (@~£150 each), put them behind LCD panels and had each one restricted so it would just launch a browser window.

Answer (score -1):

It could probably not be done for less than buying and mounting a used iPad on each wall. Of course with the iPad the employees would probably want to do things like play Angry Birds on their dashboards.